# My favourite song [of/from/by] her is...

Tags: prepositions

> - My favourite song of her is...
> - My favourite song from her is....
> - My favourite song by her is...

Which sentence is correct? Which preposition do I use?

Comment: By far the most common version is [...favorite song of **hers** is...](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22favorite+song+of+hers+is%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). That gets 40 hits in Google Books, but there are no meaningful results at all for "non-genitive" [favorite song of **her** is](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22favorite+song+of+her+is%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (the alternative prepositions ***by*** and ***from*** get 7 and 3 results respectively).

Answer (score 8):

All three are possible, depending on what is meant, but after "of" you have to use "hers" instead of "her".  A song ***of*** hers is one she performed, one she wrote, or one she possesses (in a collection of some sort).  A song ***by*** her is one she wrote or performed.  A song ***from*** her is one she issued, published, or distributed, or perhaps wrote.

I probably missed some interpretations, but the general idea is that the preposition differs depending on the relationship between her and the song.

Comment: I pretty much agree with all of this answer (+1). I'll add that the OP should be aware of two very important aspects of English.  (1) Prepositions in English are very important. Sometimes only one is allowed for a particular word but more often a word can be paired with different prepositions that give it completely different meanings. (2) English is a context-sensitive language. The meaning of an expression may change according to what was said previously and by whom. As noted, if you say a song is 'by' someone then this can mean they composed it or that they sang it depending on context.

Comment: I'm not convinced *a song of **her*** is valid at all. I know the genitive/possessive is effectively "optional" with [*a friend of **her / hers / Peter / Peter's***](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/), but regardless of whether it's a pronoun or an actual noun, *a song of **Rihanna***, for example, doesn't really work for me. I just can't see how to apply the *a painting **of / by** Van Gogh* distinction to a "song" without switching to ***about*** rather than ***of***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, "a painting of Van Gogh's" is colloquial.

Comment: I know that. My point is that "a painting of Van Gogh's" (*with* the genitive) would always mean a painting owned or painted by Van Gogh - where without the genitive, "a painting of Van Gogh" would always mean a painting *depicting* Van Gogh. That same distinction applies with pronouns, so we can differentiate *a photo of **him*** (depicting him) from *a photo of **his*** (which he took and/or owns). But I simply don't think it works at all with ***a song of him***, regardless of the intended meaning - to me, that has to be either ***about him*** or ***of his***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I agree with what you say (excepting "a song of sixpence", "Song of Solomon").

Comment: Well, the *Song of Solomon* is aka *Song of Songs*, so we'd have to be a bit careful how we "analyse" that one (to my mind, both those versions and *A Song of Sixpence* are effectively "frozen forms", so formal syntax analysis isn't necessarily appropriate anyway).

Comment: I agree except I don't see where "A song from her" would be valid. Can you elaborate on a situation where that would be correct?

Comment: @WendiKidd, Just one more song from her is all I ask.  The last time we had a song from her was 1942.  There's not a song from her pen that I don't love.

Answer (score 5):

I would say

> My favorite song by her is...

However, a more common construction is

> My favorite...song is...

Here the first ellipsis contains the name of the person whose song you like. *My favorite Miley Cyrus song is...*, *My favorite Leonard Cohen song is...*

Answer (score 0):

I would say: My favorite Bob Dylan song is "Like a Rolling Stone".
This is my favorite song by him.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use Taylor Swift as an example, because lots of people know who she is.

#### My favorite song of Taylor Swift is "Blank Spaces".

This is not valid English, but it's close and you would certainly be understood. You are referring to a possession of a person, or, a song of ***hers***. This construct might be found in more classical/archaic uses when referring to a song embodying an ideal or feeling, or perhaps a time period, such as:

> My favorite song **of hope** is, "I'll fly away."
>
> My favorite song **of the Great Depression** is "Pennies from Heaven"[ by Django Reinhardt].

With possession denoted, it is formal:

> My favorite song of Taylor Swift's is "Blank Spaces".

More specific to what you literally asked, you could use it to follow someone's mention of an artist.

> **Your friend:** Oh! I love Taylor Swift!
>
> **You:** Me too! My favorite song of hers is "Blank Spaces".

#### My favorite song from Taylor Swift is "Blank Spaces".

This is technically correct, but since you're talking about an artist, it might sound a bit awkward. "From" would more naturally be used to refer to a place, time, or thing (album, movie, record label, etc.).

> - My favorite Taylor Swift song **from this year** is "Blank Spaces".
> - My favorite song **from** Mali is [Tenere Taqqim Tossam](https://youtu.be/uMUuuW13Fp8).
> - My favorite song **from** *1989* is "Blank Spaces".
> - My favorite song **from Stax Records** is "Sittin' at the dock of the bay."

These all work. The difference is subtle, and is not crucial for effective communication.

#### My favorite song by Taylor Swift is "Blank Spaces".

**Out of the three options you gave, this is the best one out of context.** It's pretty formal, but as far as I know, it's correct. Can you see the difference? It might seem trivial to a non-native speaker. I apologize if this is confusing. Just remember when talking about a time, place, or album you can use "from". For a person, "by" is generally better.

### Consider

As @Jonah said, the most common construct is:

> **My favorite Taylor Swift song is "Blank Spaces".**